# count of array elements in php

Tags: php, arrays

I m trying to display no of elements in an array,but its showing 1 when i m trying to print the count

```
<?php
if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file('sunglasses.xml')){
trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
}
$array1=array();
foreach($xml as $syn)
{
for($i=0;$i<count($syn->productId);$i++)
{
$array1=$syn->productId;

}

}
echo count($array1, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
?>
```

There are 10 products in the xml file.So i want the count to be 10,but its printing only 1.
Please tell me whats wrong in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your formatting of code is horrible.

And yes, there might be 10 elements in the xml, but there is only one in `$array1` because only the last assignment is present. You never told to `$array1` to push values into the array, despite the fact you declared it as array. Assignation process `=` does not push values, if explicitly not called via `array_push()` or `[]` syntax.

```
$array1[] = $syn->productId;
```

Should work.

You should have tested the result at least. `var_dump()`'ing the `$array1` will give you result of only one value - the last value, and you would be able to understand that something is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Following Change in code will resolved your issue.

```
  <?php
    if(!$xml=simplexml_load_file('sunglasses.xml')){
    trigger_error('Error reading XML file',E_USER_ERROR);
    }
    $array1=array();
    foreach($xml as $syn)
    {
    for($i=0;$i<count($syn->productId);$i++)
    {
   // here need to add the result in array. not to assign value directly to array object.
    $array1[] = $syn->productId;

    }

    }
    echo count($array1, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
    ?>
```

Comment: You should at least explain why it works your way :)